# Ruby String encoding changed over versions

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, utf

I am working with a legacy project currently running on ruby 1.9.3, and am investigating moving it over the next few months to 2.3.0

We have this line of code, and this is returning different results over different ruby versions. I want to know if this is a ruby bug that got fixed, or if it is a new bug, or if it is a documented change in behaviour. A reference to relevant bug tickets would help.

```
content =  "Is your pl\xFFace available?".force_encoding("UTF-8")
content.encode("UTF-8", invalid: :replace) # some other details removed to give smallest code sample
```

Results on ruby 1.9.3, 2.0

```
"Is your pl\xFFace available?"
```

Results on ruby 2.1, 2.2, 2.3

```
"Is your pl�ace available?"
```

Essentially "\xFF" is considered invalid enough to replace, but if the `invalid: :replace` omited, it doesnt raise an error as it is supposed to. I am guessing this might be because it is a no-op because the source/target encodings are the same.

Comment: Try this: `content.to_s.gsub(/[[:cntrl:]]/, ' ')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the differences in documentation between [2.0](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-encode) and [2.1](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-encode) documentation you will see the following text disappeared in 2.1:

> Please note that conversion from an encoding enc to the same encoding enc is a no-op, i.e. the receiver is returned without any changes, and no exceptions are raised, even if there are invalid bytes.

So this behaviour where 2.0 and lower did not modify the string when the source and target encodings where the same, and 2.1+ does, appears to be an intended change.

I'm not 100% sure what your code is trying to do, but if it's trying to clean up the string from invalid UTF-8 byte sequence, you can use `valid_encoding?` and `scrub` as of Ruby 2.1:

```
irb(main):055:0* content = "Is your pl\xFFace available?"
=> "Is your pl\xFFace available?"
irb(main):056:0> content.valid_encoding?
=> false
irb(main):057:0> new = content.scrub
=> "Is your pl�ace available?"
irb(main):059:0> new.valid_encoding?
=> true
```

**EDIT:**

If you look through the 2.0 source code, you will see the `str_transcode0` function [exits immediately](https://github.com/skottler/ruby-2.0-rubygems/blob/master/transcode.c#L2689) if senc (source encode) is the same as denc (destination encode):

```
    if (senc && senc == denc) {
        return NIL_P(arg2) ? -1 : dencidx;
    }
```

In [2.1 it scrubs the data](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/transcode.c#L2703) when the encodings are the same and you explicitly asked to replace invalid sequences:

```
    if (senc && senc == denc) {
        ...
        if ((ecflags & ECONV_INVALID_MASK) && explicitly_invalid_replace) {
            dest = rb_str_scrub(str, rep);
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: So in 2.0 it was a no-op regardless, and in 2.1 and above it is a no-op unless `invalid: :replace` is explicitly requested? Very odd

Comment: Ultimately what I am trying to do is maintain behaviour, which being legacy code, I am not too sure what that is.. I think it is trying to convert non UTF-8 strings into UTF-8, so I can probably put it in an if which only checks if the encodings dont match

Comment: It seems to me it was written when ruby strings weren't encoded in UTF-8 by default. So it forced a UTF-8 representation, and then tried to clean out any illegal characters. If that's the case, I would replace the entire thing with just a `scrub` call - the string should be guaranteed to be UTF-8 now.